# Highcharts in arearange, how to disable this tooltip?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

In this picture, I would like to get rid of the yellow vertical line that is shown when the mouse is moved over. 
Notes: The yellow area is an arearange, and when mouse is moved over to the left edge, it shows the yellow vertical line on the left, same as right side.

How ever I would like to make the cursor become a pointer when mouse moves into the area, which is not showing in this attached picture.

If I use `enableMouseTracking: false`, then the mouse cursor is gone as well.

So in one sentence, get rid of the yellow line, but keep the mouse cursor to a pointer. Any idea?

thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a live demo (jsfiddle preferably) that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the vertical line that follows the mouse along the x axis, you can remove it by setting:

```
xAxis: {
    crosshair: false
}
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much.